# Win2k3 server / IIS 6 / utf-8

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003, umbraco

I'm running Umbraco on a windows 2003 server with IIS 6 and MySQL.

In the staging server we have Windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 and everything works great.

On the production server instead of the unicode chars I see `?` characters. I looked inside the MySQL db and I can see the old values (moved from the staging server) in unicode, but all values updated on the production server are saved as `?`.

I'm guessing I'm missing a setting in IIS/Win2k3/Umbraco, but I can't find it.

Anyone have experience with this type of setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your production MySQL server is a different server, did you check that MySQL was installed with UTF-8 support?

This link may be of use (ignore the Apache bits):

> [Enable UTF-8 on PHP, MySQL and Apache](http://dreweyscorner.blogspot.com/2008/01/enable-utf-8-on-php-mysql-and-apache.html)

This query (as root) should tell you what you need to know:

```
show variables like 'c%'
```